# Calcualte the limit of $\frac{\sqrt n!}{(1+\sqrt 1)(1+\sqrt 2)*...*(1+\sqrt n)}$ as n approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, factorial, infinite-product

$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt n!}{(1+\sqrt 1)(1+\sqrt 2)*...*(1+\sqrt n)}$
Any hints / solutions here? I feel like I'm stuck. The Ratio test is equal to $1$ which doesn't help at all. Intuitively, I'd say the limit of this series is $0$ but I can't think of how I would squeeze the series if the limit is in fact $0$.

Preferably no L'Hopital, as we haven't learned that yet (I don't really know if L'Hopital is even applicable in this case).

Comment: Is it $\sqrt n!$ or $\sqrt{n!}$ in the numerator?

Comment: take logarithms and estimate the pieces.